# Compare rows by ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

| ID | col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 1 | 3 |
| AB | 1 | 3 |
| CD | 2 | 4 |
| CD | 2 | 4 |
| EF | 5 | 10 |
| EF | 1 | 1 |
| GH | 5 | 10 |
| GH | 1 | 1 |

I would like to compare row within each ID, and for each column with equal values, add one point in the Total column.

Output:

| ID | col1 | Col2 | Total | mismatch_extract_col1 | mismatch_extract_Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 1 | 3 | 2 | Na | Na |
| AB | 1 | 3 | 2 | Na | Na |
| CD | 2 | 4 | 1 | Na | 4:3 |
| CD | 2 | 3 | 1 | Na | 4:3 |
| EF | 5 | 10 | 0 | Na | Na |
| EF | 1 | 1 | 0 | Na | Na |
| GH | 5 | 10 | 1 | 5:1 | Na |
| GH | 1 | 10 | 1 | 5:1 | Na |

I tried this:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(change = ifelse(col1 == lag(col1), 1, 0))
```

But it didn’t work.

Comment: Did you have an error with your existing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr) #version 1.1.0 and above
df %>% 
  mutate(Total = sum(across(col1:Col2, ~ n_distinct(.x) == 1)), .by = ID)

  ID col1 Col2 Total
1 AB    1    3     2
2 AB    1    3     2
3 CD    2    4     1
4 CD    2    3     1
5 EF    5   10     0
6 EF    1    1     0
7 GH    5   10     1
8 GH    1   10     1
```

Below `1.1.0`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Total = sum(across(col1:Col2, ~ n_distinct(.x) == 1))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have an error 'across Must be used inside dplyr verbs.'

Comment: As noted by Mael, you need to make sure you have dplyr version 1.1.0 otherwise you will get that error message. For help on updating dplyr, see this: https://sparkbyexamples.com/r-programming/install-and-update-r-packages/